# Django custom editable email template with variable and saving db by users

Tags: django, email, templates

I just want that users can create email templates with variables in django and also these templates can be edited and saved to db by users. thank yo How could I do that ? Thank you.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puLjP.jpg)

Comment: your question seems to be unclear. if you want to learn Django basics, watch [Corey Schafer Django tutorial](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p)

Comment: I just want that users can create email templates with variables in django and also these templates can be edited and saved to db by users. thank you

Comment: Thank you dear Abdul it is a part of answer. I will try to this method.